# How to suppress a pressed key using the Python package keyboard

Tags: python, keyboard, picamera

I'm trying to suppress the two pressed keys 'p' and 'q' in this script. The script is build to take pictures with *RPi* and *RPi camera*, when pressing the key 'p'. If you want to quit you press 'q'. The function `keyboard.is_pressed()` works totally fine, but prints me the pressed key in my terminal, where another `print()` should appear only. Also there is the function `keyboard.is_read()` where you can handle **suppress=True**.

Here is the used script:

```
from picamera2 import Picamera2, Preview
import time
import keyboard

cam = Picamera2()
cam.start_preview(Preview.QTGL)
cam.start()

savepath = '/home/pk/camera/image/'
imgname = "picture"

try:
    while 1:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("p"):
            request = cam.capture_request()
            request.save("main", savepath + imgname, format="png")
            print("Picture taken and saved")
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
            print("Closing camera...")
            break
finally:
    cam.stop_preview()
    cam.stop()
    cam.close()
```

Output:

pPicture taken and saved

qClosing camera...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start your print string with `\r` to clear the console line. Also I would recommend to use some method to execute the code only once when the key is pressed (in other case there will be spam of pictures when you press the key once). You can do for example:

```
from picamera2 import Picamera2, Preview
import time
import keyboard

cam = Picamera2()
cam.start_preview(Preview.QTGL)
cam.start()

savepath = '/home/pk/camera/image/'
imgname = "picture"

p_pressed = False

try:
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
            if p_pressed is False:
                p_pressed = True
                request = cam.capture_request()
                request.save("main", savepath + imgname, format="png")
                print("\rPicture taken and saved")
        else:
            p_pressed = False

        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            print("\rClosing camera...")
            break

finally:
    cam.stop_preview()
    cam.stop()
    cam.close()
```

Example output:

```
Picture taken and saved
Picture taken and saved
Picture taken and saved
Closing camera...
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much, it helped me. The only thing is that after closing the script your inputs  you did before appear in the terminal. Is that, because the function keyboard.ispressed() still hold the characters?

Comment: Yes, its because user input buffer is not cleared. You can clear it with
`termios.tcflush(sys.stdin, termios.TCIOFLUSH)`.

Comment: Thanks, all questions/problems solved